# $C(\mathbb{Q})$ and $C^{*}(\mathbb{Q})$

Tags: general-topology, ideals

Let $ X$ be a topological space. The set $C(X)$ is all continuous, real valued functions on $X$, so that $C(X) \subseteq \mathbb{R}^{X}$.

$C^* (X) = \{ f \in C(X) \mid \quad  f  \text{ is bounded} \}$

**So, my question is that how can I prove the following statement?**

> The set of all $f$ in $C(\mathbb{Q})$ for which $\lim_{x \rightarrow
> > \pi } f(x) = 0 $ **is not an idea**l in $C(\mathbb{Q})$. But the bounded
>   function  in this set do constitute an ideal  in $C^{\ast}(\mathbb{Q})$

Comment: adin = @azi = @Jak?

Comment: Or at least follow the same class and have the same Latex style...

Answer (score 1):

Call $I = \{f \in C(\mathbb{Q}): \lim_{x \to \pi} f(x) = 0\}$ and $I^\ast =  \{f \in C^\ast(\mathbb{Q}): \lim_{x \to \pi} f(x) = 0\}$.

It's clear that these are additive groups, e.g. $$\lim_{x \to \pi} (f+g)(x) = \lim_{x \to \pi}f(x) + \lim_{x \to \pi} g(x) = 0 + 0 = 0$$ and both these sets contain $0$ and are closed under $-$ as well.

The function $g(x) = \frac{1}{x-\pi}$ is well-defined and continuous on $\mathbb{Q}$ (as $\pi \notin \mathbb{Q}$). $f(x) = x-\pi \in I$, but $fg =1 \notin I$.

Bounded functions behave a bit differently: if $f \in I^\ast$ and $g \in C^\ast(X)$, then $|g(x)| \le M$ for some $M$. Hence $|fg(x)| \le Mf(x)$ and so $\lim_{x \to \pi} fg(x) = 0 \cdot M = 0$ and so $fg \in I^\ast$